# Multiply bytes to produce 16-bits, without shifting

Tags: sse, simd, avx

Still learning the art of SIMD, I have a question: I have two packed 8-bits registers that I'd like to multiply-add with `_mm_maddubs_epi16` (`pmaddubsw`) to obtain a 16-bits packed register.

I know that these bytes will produce *always* a number less that 256, so I'd like to avoid wasting the remaining 8 bits. For instance, the result of `_mm_maddubs_epi16(v1, v2)` should write the result in `r` where `XX` is, not where it will be (denoted with `__`).

```
v1  (04, 00, 0e, 00, 04, 00, 04, 00, 0a, 00, 0f, 00, 05, 00, 01, 00)
v2  (04, 00, 0e, 00, 04, 00, 04, 00, 0a, 00, 0f, 00, 05, 00, 01, 00)

r   (__, XX, __, XX, __, XX, __, XX, __, XX, __, XX, __, XX, __, XX)
```

Can I do this **without shifting** the result?

*PS*. I don't have a nice processor, I am limited to AVX instructions.

Comment: What can't you use a shift?

Comment: In your example all numbers are `<16` and `v1==v2`. If this is always the case, you can do a table-lookup using `vpshufb` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`).

Comment: @Mysticial It's not that I can't, it's that I am trying to avoid using too many operations.

Comment: @chtz Unfortunately I have only AVX, not AVX2 on my CPU.

Comment: If you don't have AVX2, you can of course use `pshufb` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your vector diagram, is the highest element at the left or the right?  Are the `XX` locations in the most or least significant byte of the `pmaddubsw` result?

### To get results in the low byte of a word, from inputs in the high byte of each word:

**Use `_mm_mulhi_epu16` so you're effectively doing `(v1 << 8) * (v2 << 8) >> 16`, producing the result in the opposite byte from the input words.**  Since you say the product is strictly less than 256, you'll get an 8-bit result in the low byte of each 16-bit word.

(If your inputs are signed, use `_mm_mulhi_epi16`, but then a negative result would be sign-extended to the full 16 bits.)

### To get results in the high byte of a word, from inputs in the low byte

You'll need to change how you load / create one of the inputs so instead of

```
         MSB LSB | MSB LSB
v1_lo   (00, 04,   00, 0e, 00, 04, 00, 04, 00, 0a, 00, 0f, 00, 05, 00, 01)
 element# 15 14   13   12 ...                                           0
```

you have this:  (both using Intel's notation where the left element is the highest number, so vector shifts like `_mm_slli_epi128` shift bytes to the left in the diagram).

```
         MSB LSB | MSB LSB 
v1_hi   (04, 00,   0e, 00, 04, 00, 04, 00, 0a, 00, 0f, 00, 05, 00, 01, 00)
 element# 15 14   13   12 ...                                           0
```

**With `v2` still having its non-zero bytes in the high half of each word element, simply `_mm_mullo_epi16(v1_hi, v2)`**, and you'll get `(v1 * v2) << 8` for free.

**If you're already unpacking bytes with zeros to obtain v1 and v2, then unpack the other way**.  If you were using `pmovzx` (`_mm_cvtepu8_epi16`), then switch to using `_mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_setzero_si128(), packed_v1 )`.

**If you were loading these vectors from memory in this already-zero-padded form, use an unaligned load offset by 1 byte so the zeros end up in the opposite location.**

---

If what you really want is to start with input bytes that aren't unpacked with zeros to start with, I don't think you can avoid that.  Or if you're masking instead of unpacking (to save shuffle-port throughput by using `_mm_and_si128` instead), you're probably going to need a shift somewhere.  You can shift *instead* of masking one way, though, using `v1_hi = _mm_slli_epi16(v, 8)`: a left-shift by 8 with word granularity will knock leave the low byte zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

Shift `v1` or `v2` and then use`_mm_mullo_epi16()`.

Possible XY Problem? My guess is that `_mm_unpacklo_epi8()` and `_mm_packus_epi16()` may be useful for you.